# How to use replace() in a useState string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, string, jsx

I am getting data from a database in a form of a string for my React.js appliaction, But when I try to apply a `<br>` tag to all `'/n'`, I get these as part of the string and not as a line break. I have tried removing the quote marks or using a JSX
`<br/>` instead, but still got the same result. What should I do?

My code looks like this:

```
const [abt, setAbt] = React.useState();
React.useEffect(() => {
  setAbt(databaseValue.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'))
}, [])
return (
  {abt}
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, React is not designed to render pure HTML, you are meant to send JSX, and `'<br>'` is not JSX.  The best approach here is to store the return as an array in your state, and then render this array.  You could use https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml  but it's not the best option.

Comment: Hey @Keith, I thought about this option but could not figure out how to use it in a useState() variable, without wrapping it inside the return. When I have tried to do: setAbt(<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: databaseValue.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')}}/>) I got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving a string, you can split it to an array and then using `map` put `<br>` between them during render:

```
function App() {
  const [abt, setAbt] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const string = "First\nSecond";
    const splitted = string.split(/\n/)
    setAbt(splitted)
  }, [])

return (
    <div className="App">
      {abt.map(slice => <>{slice} <br></br> </>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put HTML in your state.

Build the DOM you want with JSX instead.

e.g.

```
const [abt, setAbt] = React.useState("");

React.useEffect(() => {
  setAbt(databaseValue)
}, [])

const nodes = abt.split("\n").reduce( (acc, line) => {
   if (acc) {
        return [...acc, (<br />), line];
   }
   return [line]
}, null);

return <>{nodes}</>
```

… or possibly just use a `<pre>` element in the first place.